# npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 3.6.2~) but it is not going to be installed

Tags: debian, node.js, npm

I did the following steps:

1. git clone https://github.com/nibtehaz/NORTH-app.git
2. curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
3. sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
4. npm install # which caused the following error

   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    nodejs : Conflicts: npm
    npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 3.6.2~) but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

As suggested in the comments, I did

```
sudo apt install node-gyp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 node-gyp : Depends: libnode-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Step 3 produced that error, not 4.

Comment: How could I fix it?

Comment: Rather use npm I installed pnpm and I could install the above app without any problems.